# Getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined with Vue in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm a beginner with Vue.js and Laravel. Currently i'm making a Todo-list for practicing. But i'm getting this error in my console:

[Image of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpWoS.png)

> ### [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of
> undefined (reading 'completed') found in
>
> ```
> <ListItem> at resources/js/vue/listItem.vue
>        <ListView> at resources/js/vue/listView.vue
>          <App> at resources/js/vue/app.vue
>            <Root>
> ```

So I think my bug is in one of that file's right? listItem.vue, listView.vue or app.vue.

listItem.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" @change="updateCheck()" v-model="item.completed" />
    <span :class="[item.completed ? 'completed' : '', 'itemText']">
      {{ item.name }}
    </span>
    <button @click="removeItem()" class="trashcan">
      <font-awesome-icon icon="trash" />
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["item"],
  
  methods: {
    updateCheck() {
      axios
        .put("api/item/" + this.item.id, {
          item: this.item,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status == 200) {
            this.$emit("itemchanged");
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },

    removeItem() {
      axios
        .delete("api/item/" + this.item.id)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status == 200) {
            this.$emit("itemchanged");
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

listView.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
      <list-item
        :item="item"
        class="item"
        v-on:itemchanged="$emit('reloadlist')"
      />
      <list-item />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import listItem from "./listItem";

export default {
  props: ["items"],

  components: {
    listItem,
  },
};
</script>
```

app.vue:

```html
<template>
    <div class="container col-md-4 bg-light">
        <div class="heading row bg-dark">
            <h2 class="text-white text-center" id="title"> Todo List </h2>
        </div>

        <hr> 

        <div class="row">
            
            <add-item-form
                v-on:reloadlist="getList()"
             />
        </div>

        <hr> 
        <div class="row">
        <list-view 
            :items="items"
            v-on:reloadlist="getList()" />
        </div>
        
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import addItemForm from './addItemForm.vue'
import listView from './listView.vue'
export default {
  components: { 
        addItemForm, 
        listView 
    },

  data: function(){
      return {
          items:[]
      }
  },
  methods: {
      getList(){
          axios.get('api/items')
          .then(response => {
              this.items = response.data
          })
          .catch (error => {
              console.log(error);
              console.log("ERRRR:: ",error.response.data);

          })
      }
  },
  created(){
      this.getList();
  }

}
</script>
```

I can't find the bug. Does anybody have an idea what it could be?

Comment: I think the item object does not have a completed attribute.

Comment: Try to print your response.data to the console via javascript.

Comment: if you click on any of the `app.js:` links from your second error , it will show you, normally, which line is causing the error. tried and tell me

Comment: @RaximjonKomilijonov : When I try to console.log the response.data I see nothing in the console. How can I see if the object does have a completed atrribute? In the model?

Comment: @Atika : When I click on the links they bring me to the app.js file to the sections where they print the errors